# Fail to start server in browser-sync

Tags: node.js, browser-sync

I'm new to browser-sync, I tried to run the basic example but it failed.
How should I fix that error?

platform: window 7 x64, node v4.2.1

---

result in cmd:

G:\BrowsersyncExample>browser-sync start --server

[BS] Access URLs:

---

```
   Local: http://localhost:3000
External: http://10.0.44.169:3000
```

---

```
      UI: http://localhost:3001
```

UI External: http://10.0.44.169:3001

---

[BS] Serving files from: ./

events.js:141

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

```
at exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)

at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)

at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)

at doNTCallback2 (node.js:439:9)

at process._tickCallback (node.js:353:17)
```